# Sigma.js filter issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sigma.js

I am using sigma.js along with angular js to build my visualization web app.

Problem statement: I have written code in such a way that when filter criteria changes, filter module will be triggered to filter out nodes based on user selection(see code below).But, Initially for the first time filter works fine without any issue, but later on it doesn't seem to be working. It looks like it is not executing the filter predicate at all.

I tried below possible ways, but couldn't resolve the issue.

1) Destroyed and recreated the filter object for every data change trigger.

2) Unregistered and registered filter predicate.

code snippet:

```
scope.$watch('filtersettingdata',function(){
s = new sigma({
             graph: scope.data['mdata'],
             container: element.elementid,
             renderer: {
              container: document.getElementById(element.elementid),
              type: 'canvas'
             },
             settings: filtersettingdata
             });
        var filter = new sigma.plugins.filter(s);
            filter.nodesBy(
                        function(n) {
                         //predicate with new filter values
                        },'filter_name').apply();
           s.refresh();
  }
```

any help/suggestions will be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm the author of this plugin.

It is out-dated in the official sigma repository and I don't think it will work with Angular as it is.

It is now released under dual license GNU GPLv3 + commercial here: https://github.com/Linkurious/linkurious.js/tree/linkurious-version/plugins/sigma.plugins.filter

This version works with Angular and I've successfully used it in the projects of my company.

*Disclaimer:* I work at Linkurious SAS.